# Pytorch BatchNorm2d RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 64 elements not 0

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, batch-normalization

I'm using Octave Convolutions and have set up a BatchNorm2d adaptation that for some reasen is giving me

`RuntimeError: running_mean should contain 64 elements not 0`

I've set up some debugging prints to check what was wrong with my Tensors' dimensions, but was unable to find it.
Here is my class:

```
class _BatchNorm2d(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, num_features, alpha_in=0, alpha_out=0, eps=1e-5, momentum=0.1, affine=True,
               track_running_stats=True):
    super(_BatchNorm2d, self).__init__()
    hf_ch = int(num_features * (1 - alpha_out))
    lf_ch = num_features - hf_ch
    self.bnh = nn.BatchNorm2d(hf_ch)
    self.bnl = nn.BatchNorm2d(lf_ch)
  def forward(self, x):
    if isinstance(x, tuple):
        hf, lf = x
        print("IN ON BN: ",lf.shape if lf is not None else None) #DEBUGGING PRINT
        print(self.bnl)  #DEBUGGING PRINT
        hf = self.bnh(hf) if type(hf) == torch.Tensor else hf
        lf = self.bnh(lf) if type(lf) == torch.Tensor else lf #THIS IS THE LINE ACCUSING THE ERROR
        print("ENDED BN")
        return hf, lf
    else:
        return self.bnh(x)
```

Here is the printing error:

```
IN ON BN:  torch.Size([32, 64, 3, 3])
BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
```

It seems to me the function should have worked, since x has 64 channels and bn expects 64 channels.

EDIT:
May also be important to mention the error only happens on alpha value of 1. However, I do not understand it, since the volumes are still the same.

Comment: Did you load a state dict? Or did you initialise/reset the running stats of the batch norm manually?

Comment: No loading, I'm training from scratch.

Comment: Well, the error comes from the fact that `self.bnl.running_mean == torch.tensor([])`, which doesn't happen unless you modified it, either by loading a state dict or setting it manually.

Comment: All I'm doing with my BNs is initializing bias and weights. The error only happens with alpha value of 1, any other value the error doesn't happen, the initialization in all cases is the same.
Do you have any idea how can the running_mean being modified?

Comment: Trying to print the BN running_mean i found a typo, which was causing this error, thank you. :D

Comment: Okay good that you solved it. And i was wrong about modifying it. It was rather that your channels become 0 for `self.bnh` with `alpha_out=1`. Creating a BatchNorm with 0 channels will not work for any input, but it seems you are not using it when that's the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was a typo on the call for the low frequency BN.

```
    hf = self.bnh(hf) if type(hf) == torch.Tensor else hf
    lf = self.bnh(lf) if type(lf) == torch.Tensor else lf
```

Should have been

```
    hf = self.bnh(hf) if type(hf) == torch.Tensor else hf
    lf = self.bnl(lf) if type(lf) == torch.Tensor else lf
```